# cordova: android soft keyboard overlapping the input filed

Tags: cordova-plugins

i tried this code but still dos't work for me.
When the user clicks on an input field, the soft keyboard that pops up hides the input field when the latter is relatively low on the screen. The page is scrollable, so the user can scroll and see the field again, but the customer requirements define that the page will auto-scroll until the field is visible.

Comment: <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" /> not working for me please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not simple way to solve this. I solved using a handler like this:

```
 this.keyboardShowHandler = function (e) {
                            that.scroll.disable();
                            that.$el.css('bottom', (e.keyboardHeight - 30) + "px");
                            that.scroll.refresh();
                            that.scroll.scrollToElement(document.activeElement, 0, true, true);
                        };

    this.keyboardHideHandler = function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if (!cordova.plugins.Keyboard.isVisible) {
                                that.$el.css('bottom', "0px");
                                that.scroll.scrollTo(0, -100, 0);
                                that.scroll.enable();
                                that.scroll.refresh();
                            }
                        }, 300);
                    };

window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', this.keyboardShowHandler);
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', this.keyboardHideHandler);
```

But I am using iscroll, jquery and cordova keyboard plugin. You might want to adapt to your frameworks

Comment: @Del I want to adapt your code to my project, but I don't understand what `that` and `that.$el` refer to. Can you explain, please?

Comment: oh sorry, that is the context of the view above the declarations. Add just "var that = this" in the first lane, just above the first declaration